# Getting data using RESTful and backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, storage

I've been reading tons of tutorials, I really like this technology, but I am missing something.

Following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk you get JSON data from this url, http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users then you set your model, and collection.

I am not sure how to set this url on my own (for either local storage or database storage), I obviously need to set it to where I can GET the data or PUT/POST/DELETE data. I need to mention that I dont want to use PHP to send the data to the database, because this is a cordova app. Maybe setting data is beyond just using a URL, hopefully some one can make this clear, this should be easy points for most.

I am missing something easy here, because there is a reason they are not covering this topic extensively (maybe they are and I am overlooking it), but oh well ill ask anyways maybe someone can point this out :)

**Here is the ajaxPrefilter** *it kind of confuses me, I know it obviously prefilters our url to point to the data, but I am not sure how to apply an appropiate url for local storage/server side.*

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
});
```

**Edit:** Also I noticed that when I run a POST request, this url changes http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users and adds my data, this is from the RESTful services right, and what is so special about that url that it allows me to do that? In the meantime I am going to keep rewatching the backbone tutorial videos, to see what I am missing lol.

Also watching this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/understanding-backbone-js-and-the-server/ starting from the beginning he actually understands what I mean, but jeffery uses PHP, which maybe I can use with cordova (pointing to a script or something) but I would rather use javascript to send data to mysql and local storage.

**EDIT:** Okay I see heroku is a cloud based service https://www.heroku.com/ so inside that url we were using a dummy type of service to store the data.. Okay so now how do I point the url to local storage?

Finally got it!

Comment: You said a lot of things here, can you be more specific about your issue?

Comment: I get this alot, I mean Its simple following GET, POST, PUT, DELETE using backbone how do I get the data to stick on a server and on local storage. I am sorry if it's unclear to you, but the stuff in the post is what I know.. the ultimate goal is to save the object onto a server, or local storage either way, how do I setup the url to point into the right direction?

Comment: Backbone local storage adaptor: https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

Comment: Okay thanks let me read the setup, I appreciate setting me up in the right direction :)

Comment: For a server you will need a server that "listen" in that url so when a request comes it know what to do with it. In Backbone you set the collection/model url to the one you set on you server. Then just use Backbone methods and it will make the appropriate calls to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I am a noob, I am sure the way I asked this question may have gotten confusing but here is what I did.

I spent a good amount of time figuring out how to use https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage what I learned is, models and collections are well models and collections of data. I didn't think of it like that(should have been transparent from the get go, but oh well) inside the model and collection you need some data and so from the tutorial I followed the method of getting data was via http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users it contained jSON data which we could work with.

So in using local storage, we need to change where our jSON data is by using `localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("choose-some-identifier"),`

So understanding the model and collection really helps in knowing what to do. Now I just need to figure out how to add localstorage data to a server, and since I am using phonegap it would be cool to add an event listener for when the user connects to the internet and on that event submit the local storage data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [Backbone.js + Java Wine Cellar Application](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-jax-cellar). It is an application with a Backbone front end and a Java backend. You have just to download it, set up the environment and see how it works.

There is also a [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/using-backbone-js-with-a-restful-java-back-end/), the author wrote it also in PHP, just check his [blog](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/).

Comment: Thanks I came across it as well, didnt follow through though theres so much tuts on backbone so I was jumping around.. Ill take another look at it... I actually found out how to implement local storage following this https://github.com/mattzeunert/minmal-Backbone.localStorage-example but combing my existing code is causing some issues, Ill iron that out somehow.